# Submitblock error: bad-signet-blksig

Tags: segregated-witness, signet

I try to submit the block, what I mined, but it is not accepted. Also, I could not find the solution by searching the similar questions.

Setup: Centos 8 Linux, Qt programing and /bitcoincore/bitcoin-22.0rc3 with signet. The signet option is also in the config file. Generally; everything works.

1.
submitheader seems to work. I tried to modify the nonce and it was rejected, as expected.

2.
submitblock is rejected with the error message of "bad-signet-blksig".

Just by chance I met a getblocktemplate without transactions. I include it here, I hope it does not take up too long storage space.

> [mself@localhost bin]$ ./bitcoin-cli submitblock "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"

Answer: bad-signet-blksig

3.
Somewhere I read, I have to include "-signet" (./bitcoin-cli -signet submitblock ...), this case there are no error messages, but the block is not accepted, never enters into the signet blk0000x.dat blocks.

4.
I was checking the accepted blocks in the blk0000x.dat files. I found only one significant difference to my block. In the coinbase transaction, at the second output, the Script PubKey length in my case is 0x26=38 bytes. It comes from the "6a24aa21a9ed" plus the 32 bytes of SHA256(SHA256(witness root hash concatenated with witness reserved value)).

The description sad: the part after the 38-th byte are optional. On the contrary, all of the accepted blocks in the blk0000x.dat files have 0x77=119 bytes. The first 38 bytes are the same structure, as mine, but there are additional bytes attached.

Finally, my question: what did I do wrong, what should I correct?
Thanks, for any answer.

Comment: Is this *your* signet, or **the** signet? In case it's the latter, you cannot mine for it (unless you're Kalle Alm or AJ Towns; the signet's signers).

Comment: @PieterWuille Thanks for the answer. Frankly, I don't know. I set up my Bitcoin Core by following the instructions of Mr. Kalle Rosenbaum, in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6SUgWr97lA. My directory structure looks like: /home/mself/.bitcoin --> bitcoin.conf,  signet,  wallets. Should I try to install a normal, full node?

Comment: What you should do depends on what you're trying to do, which I don't know. But signet cannot be mined by everyone - so what you're doing here just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @PieterWuille It seems I misunderstood the purpose of signet; I understood that it is for software testing and it is to replace the testnet. I am sorry, I was wrong, I just wrote a mining program and I wanted to try it.